# Multi-module java-platform gradle build like maven bom

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module, maven-bom

I have made a gradle java-platform with constraints to work like maven bom.

The issue is I'm trying to have multiple submodules of it combined into a mega bom.

example:

I can create

```
external-deps: 
  build.gradle
```

but I want to end up with

```
project-deps:
  external-deps:
    build.gradle (java-platform) (like 
  internal-deps:
    build.gradle (java-platform)
  build.gradle - contains external and internal
```

The idea is that by the actual project, i can use

```
implementation platform(project-deps:x.x.x)
```

but I have no idea how to have it compile the two submodules into one, as the sub-modules do not create jars.

Can someone point me in the correct direction with some sample gradle scripts?